# How to customize the appearance (or not) of Slack blue dot on the system tray

Tags: notifications, slack, configuration

I recently started using Slack and I'm trying to customize it to have some sort of "visual clue" when something is written in a particular channel/channels. For Slack, this will be something like the blue dot on the system tray.

The problem with that blue dot is that it shows up when messages are posted in any of the channels I have joined, and I'm trying to make some channels "higher priority". This is, I don't want to be notified of every single message in every single channel I have joined but rather on 1 or 2 Channels I'm following closer.

Here are the Notification settings for my account
[image]
[image]
Is there some way to customize the tool to achieve that?

Comment: What are your settings like on Preferences > Notifications?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I just updated my original post settings to include print-screens of my Preferences > Notifications

Comment: I've found these suggestions, but they don't work for me. But they are on to something... https://gist.github.com/ruanmartinelli/8faa3c5a420de34afbab859877bc9c5f and https://www.reddit.com/r/Slack/comments/dy72th/how_to_disable_blue_dot_linux_412/

Comment: Here are some scripts to hack slack to remove the blue dot: https://superuser.com/a/1570792/233812 You might be able to do something similar to customise it. The long term solution would probably be a feature request to the slack developers.